# Hector mapping failed in corridors or tidy environmnent

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im using Hector Mapping for a lokalization the robot in a environment with a tidy walls like corridors or ramp and when trying to calculate the traveled distance I do not get any accurate results. My platform has IMU, Laser, Kinect. So when Im driving the platform up/down a ramp it is possible that the laser scans are not correctly aligned so the hector mapping not provide good results. Also changing the map resolution parameter of the Hector mapping the traveled distance also change. So what other option methods I can use to get better results??
As far as I know AMCL is not an option because I do not have encoders. If I use the robot pose ekf (which provides a pose in 3D) fusing the virtual odometry from Hector and IMU would be a better option??

Thanks, any help would be good

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63493/hector-mapping-failed-in-corridors-or-tidy-environmnent/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you properly setup the system so LIDAR data is transformed using data coming from the IMU?

Of course, if there are not enough features of the environment visible in LIDAR data (which can happen due to using a low range LIDAR and/or operating in a wide open environment), there is not much one can do about that.

Some more data about the environment you're operating in and the sensors you're using (most importantly, which LIDAR) would help in estimating the chances of making things work ;)

Again, as shown in a recent [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKI378kadp8) things work pretty well for us in a scenario/setup that sounds vaguely similar to yours (roll/pitch ramps, LIDAR, 3D (octo)map built from Kinect data).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-27**:
What do you mean properly set up the system? Im using A Hokuyo UTM-30LX/LN scanning laser range finder, able to measure distance up to 30 m in a semicircular field of 270 deg. Than A Xsens MTi inertial measurement unit (IMU) and Kinect. So my LIDAR is not low range. Any help?